# Can someone explain the disk partitions in the images below

Tags: partitioning

I have screen shots below which are confusing to understand. Can I get a detailed explanation of why they are different, why I've 5 primary partitions in windows which is not possible(BIOS) and anything I need to know to understand how disk partition works.

Windows 10:

[image: Windows 10]

Linux Mint:

[image: Linux Mint]

Comment: @Moab I've read that I can have as many logical partitions as I like in an extended partition and that a disk can only have one extended partition on wiki.

Comment: You can have one extended partition in an MBR partition table, and technically as many logical partitions as you wish, but Linux and Windows limit you to a total of 15 partitions in MBR. The unusual difference here is where your extended partition is located, Windows really likes the extended partition to be the last "primary" partition, having a regular primary partition after the extended partition causes windows to hiccup a bit.

Comment: Are you wondering why the sizes listed are different? It''s because when Windows says GB, it means 2^30 bytes, whereas when Linux Mint says it, it means 10^9 bytes. So, to convert from the Windows size to the Linux Mint size, you need to multiply by (2^30) / (10^9).

Comment: @John It's not about the sizes. I see a lot of differences between the two images like the linux one has 4 partitions of which one is extended and a 3 MB partition whereas in windows I have SIX(couldn't edit the question) primary partitions which is not possible since I'm on the old legacy BIOS.